# How to code the "Sub of button_Click" program of dynamic control array in Vb.net?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, dynamic, vb6, controls

I have used VB6 for many years. Recently, I am trying to use vb.net.

the following are button array and codes in VB6 and they work well.

```
Private Sub CommandColor_Click(Index As Integer)
     If Index = 0 Then CommandColor(Index).BackColor = vbRed
     If Index = 1 Then CommandColor(Index).BackColor = vbGreen
     If Index = 2 Then CommandColor(Index).BackColor = vbYellow
End Sub
```

- When I click `CommandColor(0)`, it changes color to red.
- When I click `CommandColor(1)`, it changes color to green.
- When I click `CommandColor(2)`, it changes color to yellow.

Now, I am trying to do the same things in VB2010. The following codes are what I have finished in establishing the dynamic control array. However, I don’t know how to code “the Sub of button_Click” in dynamic button array.  Anyone can help me? Thanks in advance.

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim CommandColor(2) As Button
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 0 To 2
            CommandColor(i) = New Button
            CommandColor(i).Text = "CommandColor" + Trim(Str(i))
            CommandColor(i).ForeColor = Color.Black
            CommandColor(i).Left = 50
            CommandColor(i).Width = 250
            CommandColor(i).Height = 50

            CommandColor(i).Top = 50 + 66 * i
            CommandColor(i).TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
            CommandColor(i).Font = New Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, 19, FontStyle.Regular)
            CommandColor(i).BackColor = Color.Silver
            Me.Controls.Add(CommandColor(i))
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its simple, the below will help,

```
AddHandler CommandColor(i).Click, AddressOf SubName
```

Below is the revisions required in your code,

```
Public Class Form1
Dim CommandColor(2) As Button
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To 2
        CommandColor(i) = New Button
        CommandColor(i).Name = "btn" & (i+1)
        CommandColor(i).Text = "CommandColor" + Trim(Str(i))
        CommandColor(i).ForeColor = Color.Black
        CommandColor(i).Left = 50
        CommandColor(i).Width = 250
        CommandColor(i).Height = 50

        CommandColor(i).Top = 50 + 66 * i
        CommandColor(i).TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
        CommandColor(i).Font = New Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, 19, FontStyle.Regular)
        CommandColor(i).BackColor = Color.Silver
        AddHandler CommandColor(i).Click, AddressOf Button_click


        Me.Controls.Add(CommandColor(i))
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Button_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
      Dim btn As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)
      Select btn.Name
           Case "btn1"
                 btn.BackColor = Color.Red
           Case "btn2"
                 btn.BackColor = Color.Green
           Case "btn3"
                 btn.BackColor = Color.Yellow
           Else
                 btn.BackColor = Color.Silver
      End Select
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Thank you very much.
It looks you add a brand new button on form1.

However, my goal is ---
There 3 button array on form1, and ….
.When I click CommandColor(0), it changes color to red.
.When I click CommandColor(1), it changes color to green.
.When I click CommandColor(2), it changes color to yellow.

Comment: I've edited the answer, you need to assign the buttons a identifier by setting the name property, the same can be used in the click event to differentiate the buttons and set colors accordingly.

Comment: @AnandSeniyar or you could just assign the index to the Tag property and use that

Comment: it works! I have learned much today. thank you veery much, Seniyar.